# accessing the web2py admin interface via wsgi

Tags: apache, wsgi, web2py, mod-proxy

The [web2py book](http://web2py.com/books/default/search/29?search=mod_proxy) states

> The administrative interface, admin, is only accessible from localhost
>   unless you run web2py behind Apache with mod_proxy. If admin detects a
>   proxy, the session cookie is set to secure and admin login does not
>   work unless the communication between the client and the proxy goes
>   over HTTPS; this is a security measure. All communications between the
>   client and admin must always be local or encrypted; otherwise an
>   attacker would be able to perform a man-in-the middle attack or a
>   replay attack and execute arbitrary code on the server.

However, I'm wondering if this means that using web2py via WSGI means I wont be able to get to the admin interface remotely.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you'll see if you try to access the administrative interface over HTTP:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin/default/index on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at yourserver.com Port 80
```

Just navigate to same page using HTTPS to access the administrative interface remotely.

https://yourserver.com/admin/default/index

Comment: What you are saying about http access to admin interface via WSGI is right. But about https, I get "unable to establish connection" ... here is my config file - http://paste.kde.org/566648/

Comment: It seems like you're denying access to the administrative interface in this line. Have you tried commenting it out or removing it?

`<LocationMatch ^/([^/]+)/appadmin>
  Deny from all
  </LocationMatch>`